# Creating 3d path of boat voyage across globe

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, path

I'm trying to create a 3d visualisation of a boat voyage following an already specified 2d map (see below)

[image]

I've played around with a few different ways to do this.  Here is the result I got from one.

[image]

For this I used curves attached to nulls at each red point, I then used a shrinkwrap to wrap it to the shape of the globe.

This is kind of the thing I'm going for but it needs to be more refined.
I also need the paths to only go over the ocean and not on the land.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with a planar map and geometry and deform it to conform a sphere.

The parametric sphere formula based on latitude longitude and radius can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440390/deforming-plane-mesh-to-sphere):

x = R*cos(lat)*cos(long)

y = R*cos(lat)*sin(long)

z = R*sin(lat)

Translating any vertex x value to longitude and y value to latitude we can deform any object to an sphere of radius R with the aid of geometry nodes.

If we do not take into account the z value of the vertices, any object will flatten and stick to the sphere.
Adding the z value of the vertex to the radius R, a deformed object will somehow retain its shape on the sphere.

Step by step:

Start with a plane with the earth texture. Set it to Shade smooth.

As latitude and longitude are angles, the plane dimensions will be pi in y and 2pi in x.
[image]

Adapt the formula above as a deformation in geometry nodes. Remember to add the z component to the radius.
[image]
That nodetree can be used with any object (just remember to apply transformations).

Deactivate the geometry nodes modifiers to make adjustments easier.
[image: Objects without geometry nodes]

[image: Objects with geometry nodes]
If the curve enters the sphere surface (like in the image above), just increase the radius in its geometry nodes modifier.

The curve can be animated keyframing the Factor Start and End in the curve settings (side panel).

Reusing the nodetree setup implies that every object sharing it is equally transformed (same position, rotation and scale) thus the apply transformations to work correctly.

If some of the objects have transform animation (eg. the boats move on the map surface), animation can be preserved with a dedicated nodetree setup applied to an arbitrary object (a Plane in the example below) with Object info nodes (Relative) referencing each object followed by a Join Geometry *before* the deformation.
[image]

**Edit: Main issues and workarounds:**

That was a quick and dirty solution to deform objects on a globe.

If we check the image below:

[image: Issues]
Latitude and longitude values (x and y of the vertices) distort noticeably at the globe poles, not much trouble if we dont get too close to that areas and the objects are small enough.

Also, the addition of the z values to the radius leads to a conical expansion of the deformed shape. We should avoid tall objects unless we like the effect (for stylized/comic deformation).

As the OP asked for a solution relating a boat path around the globe. Both issues can be avoided by deforming the path and translate the boat object along the resulting path without deforming it.

The globe will still use the original nodetree, but for the path we will assing a new geometry nodetree:
[image: Deformation Curve]

The part related to path deformation remains almost the same, note that we dont need to add z values to the radius since the curve will lie on the sphere surface and will be meshed after deformation.

The new part of the nodetree will allow to animate the curve length by factor (with a gap for object margin), its meshing, and the placement and orientation of an object as if it had a trajectory constraint. All controlled by Factor, value that can be animated to show the travel across the globe.

[image: Object follow path on Globe]

Notice that this nodetree has been optimized to access values from the Modifiers panel.
[image: Globe follow path result]

Also notice that both objects (Globe and Curve) need to be in the same position, and their radius value in the Geometry nodes modifier be the same (or slightly more in the curve to avoid entering the globe surface).

Comment: Thanks so much, that way is so much better than what I came up with.

Comment: The only issue I am having is with the boat objects. Whenever I apply the geometry node tree with the object info nodes, it either doesn't do anything or flattens the object onto the surface.

Comment: If you use the basic deformation solution, remember to add the z component of the positions to the radius to avoid flattening of geometry onto the globe surface.